# How can I determine the URL my git repo is located?

Tags: linux, git

I am to work on a project and I have initialized a git repo on a server. Let's suppose the URL of the server is

> foo.bar

and the repo is at

> /var/www/vhosts/foo.bar/httpdocs

I have created a git repo by running

```
git init
```

and then I created a .gitignore file, added whatever needed to be added, committed and from my local computer, which has ssh access to the server I have attempted to clone the repo, but I do not seem to find the correct URL or something is not set for the repo. I tried something like:

```
git clone https://foo.bar/httpdocs/.git
```

The error was

> fatal: repository 'https://foo.bar/httpdocs/.git' not found

I have tried with various pathes.

FYI: I have worked with git a lot in the past, but I have never set up a repository on a server, I have always received the path of repos created by someone else. Now I have created the repo, but I cannot seem to find out what the correct URL is. I have searched a lot to find this out, but unfortunately I did not find anything which would help me. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll be better off using the SSH approach. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server

Comment: to use https or ssh to clone the repository your computer has to be setup as a server serving the link via those protocols. instead you should add the server as a remote and use `git push` to push your local version to the server.. oh edit saw u are trying to copy from one computer to another... you need a https or ssh server that will serve the link, git doesn't include that

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you! Can you transform this into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to communicate via SSH, you need the SSH link, not the HTTP(S) link:

```
git clone <user>@foo.bar:/var/www/vhost/foo.bar/httpdocs/.git
```

You need `git` and `sshd` (or `openssh-server`) installed on the remote server, and add your SSH key to the server, under the correct user (with `ssh-copy-id`, of course).

Comment: I actually solved it using git clone myuser@foo.bar:/var/www/vhosts/foo.bar/httpdocs, inspired by @ceejayoz's comment.

Comment: @LajosArpad Ah yes that's also possible and it should be the canonical SSH link format.

Comment: I just needed that small information, which was very very nice to come after hours of torture.

Comment: I have added the foo.bar to the command to make it more consistent with my comment and understandable for future visitors. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -3):

This is pramar error.

The error is in line:

cit clone https://foo.bar/httpdocs/.git

you can try:

git clone https://foo.bar/httpdocs/.git

good luck.